# Symfony form collections and JSON post requests with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I currently have a form setup where the only element is a collection so we can submit store products to the API endpoint.

The way I have implemented this in the controller feels wrong and I'm not happy with the response when the form has errors. So I'm just wondering if theres a more standardised approach to this.

An example POST payload would look like this JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "productId": 12,
        "price": 12.99
    },
    {
        "productId": 13,
        "price": 15.99
    }
]
```

I have my FOSRestBundle controller action setup as followed, where I'm doing a JSON decode and building an array with the products parameter for the form.  I can't help but feel there must be a better way of doing this?

```
/**
 * @Post("/api/store/products")
 * @View
 */
public function postProductsAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductsType($this->em));
    $form->submit(['products' => json_decode($request->getContent(), true)]);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // save logic
    }

    return $form;
}
```

My form for the collection:

```
class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('products', 'collection', [
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'type' => new ProductType()
        ]);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

The product form type.

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productId', 'entity', [
                'class' => 'CatalogueBundle:Product',
                'property_path' => 'product'
                // some more unrelated options...
            ])
            ->add('price', 'number');
    }
}
```

Then theres the issue of the failed validation JSON response. Which looks like this:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": {
        "children": {
            "products": {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": {
                            "productId": {
                                "errors": [
                                    "You must provide a productId."
                                ]
                            },
                            "price": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The frontend team isn't going to like this response! Feels like theres no need for it to be so deeply nested.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to use FOSRestBundle's BodyListener. If it's correctly setup, you should receive the request parameters already decoded as an array.

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
```

See the body listener's doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html#body-listener

2) To have more user-friendly form's errors, use one of the FOSRestBundle normalizer: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/tree/master/Serializer/Normalizer

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#forms-and-views